# vim specific indentation for markdown

Tags: comments, filetype-markdown, plugin-vim-autoformat

I want the indentation in markdown file as follows

```
 - [ ] Here is some text. When I press enter
 - [ ] <--- This entire thing should get populated.
```

It means `- [ ]` should be copied onto the next line. I have tried setting comments variable in vim to accommodate the indentation for the same. I have tried installing multiple markdown plugins, but they don't seem to fix the indentation issue. Is there anyway we could do this ?

I would also be great if someone knows a plugin which could accomplish this too.

**NOTE:-** It should also work for nested lists as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plugin that will accomplish what you are looking for is [vim-orgmode](https://github.com/jceb/vim-orgmode). This will let you check and uncheck boxes in a convenient way.

You should also be able to achieve (most of) the functionality in question using Vim comments. Try clearing your comment settings if necessary

```
:set comments=
```

then doing

```
:set formatoptions+=cro
:set comments+=:-\ [\ ]
```

Note the backslashes before the spaces, which you were probably missing. This will handle nested lists automatically based on the indent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew about org mode, but I just didn't want to use it, because I didn't need that much functionality. I just wanted only that particular completion functionality. Didn't know that spaces need to be escaped!